# Selenium C# Getting values from a Column of a table and turn them into a list of String

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I need to get the values of the 2 column and turn them into a list of String.Can someone show me how to do it? Thank you very much

```
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[2]/div/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
            IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
            IList<IWebElement> rowtd;
            var Code1 = new List<string>();
            foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
            {
                rowtd = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
                var tableData = rowtd.ToString();
                Code1.Add(tableData);
            }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdTXK.png)

I'm testing the Search function and I want to compare the results with the input. Full test code of the Search function:

```
public void Search_XE_with_Name(String Name)
        {

            Login();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL + "/app/admin/xe-group11");
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            Thread.Sleep(8000);
            //Act

            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NAME")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("xE_NAME")).SendKeys(Name);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7);

            IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/span[3]/button/i"));
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


            //IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[2]/div/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
            //IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
            //List<String> Name1 = new List<String>();

            IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/app-root/ng-component/div/div/div[2]/ng-component/div[2]/div/p-table/div/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody"));
            IList<IWebElement> rows = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
            //IList<IWebElement> rowtd;
            List<string> Code1 = new List<string>();

            foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
            {
                var secondColumn = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[2];
                Code1.Add(secondColumn.Text);
            }

            foreach (String codes in Code1)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(codes, Name);
            }

        
            
            driver.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use an index to always get the 2nd column of each row...

```
foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
   var secondColumn = tableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[1];
   Code1.Add(secondColumn.Text);
}
```

Comment: God bless you Sir. I've lost hope that someone would answer this so I haven't checked for quite a time. Your answer help me a lot. I have another problem though. I'm testing Search function. I want to Asert.AreEqual the Search result and the  Input.But it seems that my code takes the values of the table Before I click the Search button not After.I have added my full test code sir. How can I fix this? I would be very grateful if you can help me with this too sir.